# how can I install grails plugin in ant build?

Tags: grails, ant, grails-plugin

I am using ant build tool for my Grails 1.3.7 project.
I verified all Grails 1.3.7 documentation too. Even I am not able to find how to install(add) a plugin in ant build tool(build.xml).

Comment: check this page https://grails.org/plugin/grails-ant

Comment: `grails install-plugin grails-ant`

Answer (score 0):

Install with `grails install-plugin /home/user/grails-someplugin-1.0.zip`